# Sequential Job Schedule using Quartz in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

Sequential Job Schedule using Quartz in Spring

I have **three** or more jobs which depends on their respective previous jobs and they will run in the sequential order. If `Job 1` finished `Job 2` run and when `Job 2` finished `Job 3` run. If any error occurred in previous `Job` then next triggered **Jobs** will not be fired. I tried to know about **Job-chaining** using **quartz** but can't able to get it through.

The Jobs sequence are as per below

```
Job 1 -> Job 2 -> Job 3
```

we defined their respective beans in **quartz.xml** as per below

```
<beans ...>
    <bean name="scheduler1"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
                <property name="jobClass"
                    value="com.abc.xyz.schedular.Scheduler1" />
                <property name="durability" value="true" />
            </bean>
            <bean id="trigger1"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
                <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduler1" />
                <property name="cronExpression" value="${scheduler1.cronExpression}" />
            </bean>
          <bean name="scheduler2"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
                <property name="jobClass"
                    value="com.abc.xyz.schedular.Scheduler2" />
                <property name="durability" value="true" />
            </bean>
            <bean id="trigger2"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
                <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduler2" />
                <property name="cronExpression" value="${scheduler2.cronExpression}" />
            </bean>
            <bean name="scheduler3"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
                <property name="jobClass"
                    value="com.abc.xyz.schedular.Scheduler3" />
                <property name="durability" value="true" />
            </bean>
            <bean id="trigger3"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
                <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduler3" />
                <property name="cronExpression" value="${scheduler3.cronExpression}" />
            </bean>
        <bean name="jobScheduler"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
            <property name="triggers">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="trigger1" />
                    <ref bean="trigger2" />
                    <ref bean="trigger3" />
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="autoStartup" value="${jobScheduler.autoStartup}" />
        </bean>
</beans>
```

In the above xml files the cron expressions are as follows   **scheduler1.cronExpression**=0 1 0 * * ?  , **scheduler2.cronExpression**=0 2 0 * * ?  , **scheduler3.cronExpression**=0 3 0 * * ? and the **jobScheduler.autoStartup**=true .

The Schedular class for **Scheduler1.java** , **Scheduler2.java** , **Scheduler3.java** is defined below.

```
public class Scheduler1 implements Job {

    private static final Logger log = (Logger) LogManager
            .getLogger(Scheduler.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
            /*
             *  doing my heavy Process
             */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in setExpiredAllPlans Schedular1 ");
        }
    }
}


public class Scheduler2 implements Job {

    private static final Logger log = (Logger) LogManager
            .getLogger(Scheduler.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
            /*
             *  doing my heavy Process
             */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in Schedular2 ");
        }
    }
}


public class Scheduler3 implements Job {

    private static final Logger log = (Logger) LogManager
            .getLogger(Scheduler.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
            /*
             *  doing my heavy Process
             */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in setExpiredAllPlans Schedular3 ");
        }
    }
}
```

Now how would i able to chain the jobs using above configuration because sometimes these heavy process take more than 1 minute so i don't want to start the next fire job until previous job is completed.
If you have any concern/clarification ,please revert me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to run them sequentially, why don't you just put them all in the same `Job`?

Comment: as @heenenee said, or if your jobs count is configurable and/or changes over the time, you probably need to use some publish-subscribe layer over your jobs, which may allow you to even change your chain configuration in runtime.

Comment: Hi @heenenee and Maks , Thanks for reply , i can put them into single job that is i m doing currently but i want to configure job chaining in the project thats why i asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

To chain the execution of your jobs, you will need to implement a [JobListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/JobListener.html). In its *[jobWasExecuted](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/JobListener.html#jobWasExecuted(org.quartz.JobExecutionContext,%20org.quartz.JobExecutionException))* event handler you will need to define your job chaining logic so that your jobs are executed in a sequential order regardless of how long the executions of individual jobs take. In that case you will only need a trigger for the very first job (Job 1) as the chained jobs (Job 2 and Job 3) will be triggered "manually" from the event handler.

You can also use the [JobChainingJobListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html) implementation that enables you to programmatically define simple job chains in your application. To define your job chain, you will use the *[addJobChainLink](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html#addJobChainLink(org.quartz.JobKey,%20org.quartz.JobKey))* method.

If you would like a robust solution that will allow you to avoid hard-coding the job chaining logic in your application code while letting you modify your job chaining rules at runtime through a GUI without the need to touch, redeploy and restart your application, you can consider using our product [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com/documentation/features#job-chaining). QuartzDesk comes with a powerful job chaining engine that allows you to implement all sorts of common job chaining scenarios including scheduled (i.e. not immediate) executions of your chained (target) jobs, multiple target jobs, local/remote target jobs etc.

[image]